# Activating wordpress plugins breaks jquery effects

Tags: javascript, wordpress, jquery

I'm currently working on converting an HTML5 template called [Rekreato](http://demo.drythemes.com/rekreato/index.html) into a wordpress theme. I've managed to set up a bare-bones theme, but whenever I activate any plugins with jQuery scripts, a few of my jQuery effects are broken. Specifically, in Firefox debugger I get --

> TypeError: jQuery.easing[jQuery.easing.def] is not a function @
>   jquery.easing.1.3.js:46

Here is the [page in question](http://beardsavvy.ca/dev/newleaf). You can see about halfway down there is an image slider that is not functional. I have left one plugin active, called WP eMember.

I've tried a number of things like configuring my theme as a child theme, wrapping jquery.easing.1.3 in a document ready function, and moving the script call around in the code, but to no avail. I'm not even sure that the easing script is at fault. The answer is probably staring me in the face, but I can't seem to figure it out. Many thanks in advance.

EDIT: Excellent suggestion from markratledge. I put the scripts in functions.php with wp_register_script() and wp_enqueue_script(). At first I was very confused that even more things were broken. Reading further, I saw that since Wordpress uses a noConflict wrapper around its built-in jQuery library, the $ shortcut is unavailable. So, I went through all of my scripts that were showing errors in the inspector and swapped '$' with 'jQuery'. Voila! Everything jives. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Function Reference/wp enqueue script « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) on how to load JS in WordPress themes and avoid jQuery errors, with examples shown.

You're loading a bunch of jQuery by direct link, but then `wp_head` comes in and loads more jQuery for the plugins, and collisions occur. I.e., the two different main jQuery libraries; check in the Firefox console to get a list of all the JS that is loading.

From that doc:

> `wp_enqueue_script` links a script file to the generated page at the right time according
>   to the script dependencies, if the script has not been already
>   included and if all the dependencies have been registered. You could
>   either link a script with a handle previously registered using the
>   wp_register_script() function, or provide this function with all the
>   parameters necessary to link a script.
>
> This is the recommended method of linking JavaScript to a WordPress
>   generated page.